# Docker --add-host flags not working for registry 2.0 webhooks notifications

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I had to connect to the Docker host (where my application is running at 8080) from within my registry container. To enable this, i passed the Docker host's IP Address to the container using the "--add-host" flag.  Followed the [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1143) and [Command line reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029213427/http://docs.docker.com:80/reference/commandline/run/#adding-entries-to-a-container-hosts-file). I enabled my application endpoint:8080 in below config.yml to send webhooks notifications from registry.

This set up was working until yesterday where my application received all kinds of push/pull event notifications in docker version 1.8.2. However, it stopped working today. I tried upgrading from 1.8.2 to 1.8.3 to see if that fixes it, but no luck so far. Not sure if this is related to any Docker 1.9 release updates.

Any inputs/suggestions/pointers would be much appreciated.

Docker version:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 06:06:01 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 06:06:01 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Launching registry container with this command

```
$docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --add-host=dockerhost:$(ip route | awk '/docker0/ { print $NF }') --name docker_registry -v ~/docker-registry/images:/var/lib/registry -v ~/docker-registry/config/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml registry:2.1.1
```

config.yml looks like this, configured to send webhooks notification to my application endpoint:8080 (appListener):

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
notifications:
  endpoints:
    - name: appListener
      url: http://dockerhost:8080/event
      headers:
        Authorization:
      timeout: 500ms
      threshold: 5
      backoff: 1s
```

Error  Logs in docker_registry:

```
time="2015-10-30T23:50:15Z" level=warning msg="httpSink{http://dockerhost:8080/event} encountered too many errors, backing off"
time="2015-10-30T23:50:16Z" level=error msg="retryingsink: error writing events: httpSink{http://dockerhost:8080/event}: error posting: Post http://dockerhost:8080/event: dial tcp 172.17.42.1:8080: connection refused, retrying"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with application.properties file in maven application where server.address was specified as 127.0.0.1.

```
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.port=8080
```

Fixing that to below "server.address=dockerhost", same as "--add-host=dockerhost:.." in docker run command fixed it.

```
server.address=dockerhost
server.port=8080
```